# How can I Insert a Path in Pandas .read_table ou read CSV file as a Variable

Tags: python

im tring to input a variable with my target path in pd.read_table, but it is not working.
Is is possible to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

TXT = "C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Infoprex - Olivais.txt"

    DfOlivais = pd.read_table(f'{TXT}', sep="\t", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python',header=0)
```

Comment: An error message would help, but it looks like you are using backslashes which are the escape character inside ordinary strings, which could lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this if you are reading a txt file

```
import pandas as pd
import os

TXT = r"C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Infoprex - Olivais.txt"
DfOlivais = pd.read_table(TXT, sep="\t", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I believe this should get you the same results and a lot easier to read

Comment: I already try that. It generates a syntaxError:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

But if i just use the path the code run like butter.
DfOlivais = pd.read_table(r"C:\Users\ricar\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Infoprex - Olivais.txt", sep="\t", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", engine='python',header=0)